# What are the powers of Technovore and what is its origin?

Tags: marvel

In the animated movie **Iron Man: Rise of the Technovore**, I came across Technovore as a Marvel character for the first time, there is not a lot of information available about this character. What are the powers of this character in the movie? Is it just made of nano technology or it has some power of organic matter also. Is the origin of the character same as in comics or is it changed for the movie?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technovore